# kleptography SETUP attack in ecdsa

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, dsa, attack

I'm trying to implement kleptography SETUP attack of ecdsa with python.
Just a simply script to verify the algorithm. However i can't get the right output as the paper said. Where is the problem? Can anyone help?

[image: The algorithm]

```
from ecpy.curves import Curve, Point
import hashlib
import gmpy

cv = Curve.get_curve('secp256k1')
G = Point(0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
          0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8,
          cv)


def sign(k, d, hash):
    R = k * G
    r1 = R.x % p
    k_ = int(gmpy.invert(k, p))
    s1 = (k_ * (hash + d * r1)) % p
    return (r1, s1)


(a, b, h, e) = (11, 22, 33, 44)
hash1 = 987654321
hash2 = 77777
d = 123
v = 456
p = 2 ** 256 - 2 ** 32 - 977
j = 0
u = 1

pKey1 = d * G
V = v * G

k1 = 8888
(r1, s1) = sign(k1, d, hash1)
print("(r1, s1): ", (r1, s1))

z = a * k1 * G + b * k1 * V + h * j * G + e * u * V
k2 = hashlib.sha256(str(z).encode('ASCII')).digest()
k2 = int.from_bytes(k2, 'big')
(r2, s2) = sign(k2, v, hash2)
print("(r2, s2): ", (r2, s2))

R1 = Point(x=r1, y=(cv.y_recover(x=r1)), curve=cv)
Z1 = a * R1 + b * v * R1
Z2 = Z1 + h * j * G + e * u * V
K2 = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(str(Z2).encode('ASCII')).digest(), 'big')
print(K2 * G.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Just implemented it in rust-lang.
And this is my code. Just simply implemented. **Need further work & don't take it seriously**

```
use curv::arithmetic::Converter;
use curv::elliptic::curves::{ Point, Scalar, Secp256k1};
use curv::BigInt;
use openssl::hash::{Hasher, MessageDigest};

fn main() {
    let mut hasher = Hasher::new(MessageDigest::sha256()).unwrap();

    // Attacker's private key
    let v = Scalar::<Secp256k1>::random();
    // Attacker's public key
    let V = Point::generator() * v.clone();

    // User's private key
    let D = Scalar::<Secp256k1>::random();
    println!("{:?}", D.to_bigint());
    // User's public key
    let Q = Point::generator() * D.clone();

    let message1 = String::from("First message to sign");
    let message2 = String::from("Second message to sign");

    hasher.update(message1.as_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let m1: Scalar<Secp256k1> =
        Scalar::from_bigint(&(BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref())));

    let k1 = Scalar::<Secp256k1>::random();
    let signaturePoint1 = Point::generator() * k1.clone();
    let r1 = Scalar::from_bigint(&(signaturePoint1.x_coord().unwrap()));
    let s1 = k1.clone().invert().unwrap() * (m1.clone() + D.clone() * r1.clone());

    println!("r1: {:?}", r1.to_bigint());
    println!("s1: {:?}", s1.to_bigint());

    hasher.update(message2.as_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let m2: Scalar<Secp256k1> =
        Scalar::from_bigint(&(BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref())));

    let a: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::random();
    let b: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::random();
    let h: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::random();
    let e: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::random();
    let u: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::from(0 as u16);
    let j: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::from(0 as u16);

    let Z = a.clone() * k1.clone() * Point::generator()
        + b.clone() * k1.clone() * V.clone()
        + j.clone() * h.clone() * Point::generator()
        + u.clone() * e.clone() * V.clone();
    let zX = Z.x_coord().unwrap();
    hasher.update(&zX.to_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let hash =
        Scalar::<Secp256k1>::from_bigint(&(BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref())));
    let k2 = hash;
    let signaturePoint2 = k2.clone() * Point::generator();
    let r2 = Scalar::<Secp256k1>::from_bigint(&signaturePoint2.x_coord().unwrap());
    let s2 = k2.clone().invert().unwrap() * (m2.clone() + r2.clone() * D.clone());
    println!("r2: {:?}", r2.to_bigint());
    println!("s2: {:?}", s2.to_bigint());
    let recovered = ExtractUsersPrivateKey(message1, message2, a, b, h, e, r1, s1, r2, s2, v, V, Q);
    println!("{:?}", recovered.to_bigint());
}

fn ExtractUsersPrivateKey(
    message1: String,
    message2: String,
    a: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    b: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    h: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    e: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    r1: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    s1: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    r2: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    s2: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    attackerPrivate: Scalar<Secp256k1>,
    attackerPublic: Point<Secp256k1>,
    userPublic: Point<Secp256k1>,
) -> Scalar<Secp256k1> {
    let mut hasher = Hasher::new(MessageDigest::sha256()).unwrap();

    hasher.update(message1.as_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let m1: Scalar<Secp256k1> =
        Scalar::from_bigint(&(BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref())));

    hasher.update(message2.as_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let m2: Scalar<Secp256k1> =
        Scalar::from_bigint(&(BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref())));
    let w = s1.invert().unwrap();
    let u1 = m1.clone() * w.clone();
    let u2 = r1.clone() * w.clone();
    let verifyPoint = u1.clone() * Point::generator() + u2.clone() * userPublic.clone();

    let Z1 = verifyPoint.clone() * a.clone()
        + (verifyPoint.clone() * b.clone() * attackerPrivate.clone());

    let u: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::from(0 as u16);
    let j: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::from(0 as u16);
    let Z2 = Z1.clone()
        + j.clone() * h.clone() * Point::generator()
        + u.clone() * e.clone() * attackerPublic.clone();
    let zX: Scalar<Secp256k1> = Scalar::from_bigint(&Z2.x_coord().unwrap());
    hasher.update(&zX.to_bigint().to_bytes()).expect("Hash error");
    let hash: Scalar<Secp256k1> =
        Scalar::from_bigint(&BigInt::from_bytes(hasher.finish().unwrap().as_ref()));
    let kCandiate = hash.clone();
    let verifyPointCandiate = kCandiate.clone() * Point::generator();
    let rCandiate = verifyPointCandiate.x_coord().unwrap();
    if rCandiate == r2.to_bigint() {
        return (s2.clone() * kCandiate.clone() - m2) * (r2.invert().unwrap());
    }
    Scalar::random()
}
```

This is the library I'm using

```
[dependencies]
curv-kzen = "0.8"
openssl = "0.10"
openssl-sys = "0.9"
```